# Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication error on winforms login

Tags: c#, winforms

Good day.
I have been stuck on a particularly irritating issue.
I have set up a Domain and added two machines (a Database Server and an Interface server) both are running windows server 2012.

I have an application which utilises Impersonation to connect to the DB server via windows authentication and utilises the entered login details the USER provides on the application.

The issue i am running into is that whenever i click the submit button with the USER entered credentials, I receive a "**Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.** " and though my impersonation class is [retty straightforward as seen below it still gives me the error.

```
public class ImpersonateUser
{
   [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
   public static extern bool LogonUser(
      String lpszUsername,
      String lpszDomain,
      String lpszPassword,
      int dwLogonType,
      int dwLogonProvider,
      ref IntPtr phToken);

   [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
   public extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

   private static IntPtr tokenHandle = new IntPtr(0);
   private static WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser;

   // If you incorporate this code into a DLL, be sure to demand that it
   // runs with FullTrust.
   [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
   public void Impersonate(string domainName, string userName, string password) 
   {
     try {

        // Use the unmanaged LogonUser function to get the user token for
        // the specified user, domain, and password.
        // Xc: ---- For const descriptions see
        // ms-help://MS.MSDNQTR.v80.en/MS.MSDN.v80/MS.WIN32COM.v10.en/secauthn/security/logonuser.htm
        const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
        // Passing this parameter causes LogonUser to create a primary token.
        const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
        // const int LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 3; 
        tokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

        // Call  LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token.
        // Xc: ---- LogonUser documentation
        // ms-help://MS.MSDNQTR.v80.en/MS.MSDN.v80/MS.WIN32COM.v10.en/secauthn/security/logonuser.htm
        bool returnValue = LogonUser(
            userName,
            domainName,
            password,
            LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, // Xc:-- will cache logon information for disconnected operations
            /* LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, // Xc:-- This type of access is faster */
            LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
            ref tokenHandle);         // tokenHandle - new security token


        if (false == returnValue) {
           int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
           Console.WriteLine("LogonUser call failed with error code : " +
               ret);
           throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret);
        }

        // Xc: ---- Assume new identity
        WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(tokenHandle);
        impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate();

     }
     catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred. " + ex.Message);
     }
  }

   // Stops impersonation
   public void Undo() {
      impersonatedUser.Undo();
      // Free the tokens.
      if (tokenHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
         CloseHandle(tokenHandle);
   }
}
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this? I am at my wits end.

Comment: Have you tested whether the user has the Interactive (`SE_INTERACTIVE_LOGON_NAME`) account right? Maybe, try with `LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT` instead.

Comment: Also, read the introduction text of this function: [LogonUserW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonuserw) -- *The LogonUser function attempts to log a user on to the local computer. The local computer is the computer from which LogonUser was called. You cannot use LogonUser to log on to a remote computer.*. If you use the token to access network resources in different domains, there must be a Trust set between the domains.